# Converting Task<Reader<A, B>> to ReaderTask<A, B> with FP-TS

Tags: typescript, fp-ts

I'm looking for a concise way of converting a `Task<Reader<A, B>>` to `ReaderTask<A, B>` using TypeScript. The following seems to work but I'm wondering if the function is already available in FP-TS.

```js
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable';
import { Task, map } from 'fp-ts/lib/Task';
import { Reader } from 'fp-ts/lib/Reader';
import { ReaderTask } from 'fp-ts/lib/ReaderTask';

function fromTaskReader<A, B>(taskReader: Task<Reader<A, B>>): ReaderTask<A, B> {
  return (context: A): Task<B> => pipe(
    taskReader,
    map((reader) => reader(context)),
  );
}
```

Comment: If you can't find it you should make a pr